# Lenovo Thinkpad X201, wireless switching off

Tags: thinkpad

I have had a long term problem with my Thinkpad randomly switching off the wireless. I haven't yet been able to discern any apparent pattern as to when or why it does it.

I have recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and the problem still persists.

To resolve it each time, I just need to Fn+F5 and then switch it back on. However, it is irritating and I was wondering if anyone else had encountered this and knew what the solution was?

Comment: Under Device Manager / wireless adapter Properties or any bundled software that controls the adapter, check if there's an option to turn off the device's power saving/sleep mode.

Comment: This is helpful. I have unchecked the option to 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power'. I'll run with this for a few days and see how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved (at the suggestion of @Karan) by switching off the option 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' for the wireless adapter.

I didn't originally think this was the issue since the Thinkpad seemed to randomly switch it off even after no appreciable time delay (e.g. just switching between wireless networks). Nevertheless, this seems to have solved the problem.

This setting is reached by going to the device manager (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> , then click Device Manager) and looking for the Wireless Adapter under 'Network adapters').

[image: Windows 8 Power Management]

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to replace my wireless card a couple times. For me, it seems to start doing that and going on the fritz a few months before it dies.

Comment: The site's Q&A format reserves answers for solutions to the question.  This post is really a comment rather than an answer. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).  Non-answers tend to attract downvotes and are subject to deletion.